# If value not found in tibble, give NA R

Tags: r, purrr

I have following problem. I have list column of tibbles, which I want to clean up by just taking certain values and creating new tibble from them. Problem is that not all columns are available in original tibble, so I would like to replace them with NA. Example will clear this one.

DATA:

```
tbl <- tibble(list_col = list(tibble(id = c("A", "B", "C"),
                                    val1 = c(1, 2, 3),
                                    val2 = c(11, 22, 33)),
                             tibble(id = c("A", "B", "C"),
                                    val1 = c(1, 2, 3))))
```

Real data is more complicated, but this will suffice to show problem. I have created function to pick columns I would like to have. I wrap everything now days with `possibly` to avoid falling short.

```
get_res <- possibly(function(ls){
  out = tibble(id = ls$id,
               val1 = ls$val1,
               val2 = ls$val2)
  return(out)
}, otherwise = NA)
```

Then I usually `map` function with `mutate` to create clean column.

```
tbl %>% 
  mutate(clean = map(list_col, get_res))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  list_col         clean           
  <list>           <list>          
1 <tibble [3 x 3]> <tibble [3 x 3]>
2 <tibble [3 x 2]> <lgl [1]>       
Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: 'val2'.
```

Expected result, but how can I go around this and replace val2 with NA in second tibble and return values what I have there?

I thought this would have worked:

```
get_res2 <- possibly(function(ls){
  out = tibble(id = ls$id,
               val1 = ls$val1,
               val2 = tryCatch(ls$val2, error=function(e) NA))
  return(out)
}, otherwise = NA)
```

But this will fail as well.

Comment: Since your function explicitly uses `id`, `val1`, `val2`, can we assume that your actual case also has only few columns with known names? So that we don't need to look for all possible column names in `tbl` first.

Comment: I know all the column names I want to pull, so no worries there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a nice trick for this:

```
tbl %>% 
  mutate(clean = map(list_col, bind_rows,
                     tibble(id = character(), val1 = double(), val2 = double())))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   list_col         clean           
#   <list>           <list>          
# 1 <tibble [3 × 3]> <tibble [3 × 3]>
# 2 <tibble [3 × 2]> <tibble [3 × 3]>
```

Exploiting the fact that you know in advance what the columns are + creating an empty `tibble` + `bind_rows` to fill the empty ones with `NA`.

Comment: looks like simple ifelse(is.null(ls$val2), NA, ls$val2) works as well.